# AdvancedFilter behavior not consistent?

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: Answered by @Magnetron below.

I am trouble shooting some old code and I can work around the problem but wanted to know why the behavior is not consistent for AdvancedFilter using Unique:=True.

Here is the issue, a data table is created and there are customers and rig locations assigned in the table along with other parameters.

The code attempts to find the unique number of customers:

```
'Specialized list of customers for the month
ThisWB.Worksheets("May").Range(("D3:D" & LastDataRow)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ThisWB.Worksheets("May").Range("AA1"), Unique:=True

'define a temp last row on the unique row
tempLR = ThisWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row

holderCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWB.Worksheets("May").Range("AA1:AA" & tempLR)) - 1
```

This code doubles up the first customer item when creating the "unique" customer list as a header is created on the fly.  Seems manageable.  The sub then subtracts 1 from the CountA on the a range defined by this new "list". A correct number of Customers results by subtracting the duplicate (header).

The range is cleared and then . . .

Literally 4 lines later the same call is made on a different column and no header is created, the list is unique, subtracting 1 results in the the incorrect unique number, so I have removed it as it was giving one less than what the count should be.

```
'Specialized list of rigs for the month
ThisWB.Worksheets("May").Range(("F3:F" & LastDataRow)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ThisWB.Worksheets("May").Range("AA1"), Unique:=True

'define a temp last row on the unique row
tempLR = ThisWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row

holderCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWB.Worksheets("May").Range("AA1:AA" & tempLR))
```

This behavior occurs each month, twelve times, the header is created in the first call, no header is created in the second call.  Of course a blank row is represented if present, but gets ignored in the CountA.

Being able to account for this unique behavior aside, why does this happen?  The AdvancedFilter function should not act differently in an alternating fashion, say different for column D than column F.  I feel either the created header should always be present or never present.

Wanted to share this observation.

Cheers - WWC

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem, for me it always return as if the first cell is the header. Couldn't it be that in your second case, in the Column F the value in the first cell (F3) is unique, so it doesn't get repeated?

Comment: It is possible that the column F values are unique on their own vs. the Column D values, I will make a duplicate and see what happens.

Comment: ^^^^@Magnetron: You nailed it.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Advanced Filter function always consider that the data have headers. In your column F, the value in the first cell is unique, so it doesn't get duplicated. On the other hand, on the D column range, the first value is set as the header but it has multiple occurences, so it appears again as tbale data.

To correct the behaviour, just add a header to all your data, and you can subtract 1 to count the values.